# Select a datetime - wrong

Tags: mysql, datetime, select

this is a record i have on my `mysql` database:

```
event_id    int(11)         52
event_name  varchar(127)    event 3
start_date  datetime        2015-07-03 17:10:00
end_date    datetime        2015-07-03 20:00:00
details                     test
```

after a select

```
SELECT * FROM events WHERE event_id = 52
```

i see it

```
event_id    int(11)         52
event_name  varchar(127)    event 3
start_date  datetime        2015-07-06 08:00:00  //problems here
end_date    datetime        2015-07-03 09:00:00  //and here
details                     test
```

as you can see the datetime fields change!
could somebody tell me why and what could i do to solve the problem?

thank you

Comment: start_date is crazy, it is 3 days in difference. This can not be TZ thing, as I answered below.

Comment: You must have some kind of logic that updates the startdate. Extend the event? Different event? Trigger upon insert?

Comment: Check if there is a trigger, `show triggers`

Answer (score 1):

Must be as you have set some timezone, should be UTC.

Run:

```
select @@system_time_zone;

select timediff( NOW(), UTC_TIMESTAMP );
```

Check your [Mysql config for TIMEZONE support](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/time-zone-support.html) as it should have either
`default_time_zone='+00:00'` or `timezone='UTC'`

Comment: But wait a second... this can not be TZ thing, how can 2015-07-03 17:10:00 become 2015-07-06 08:00:00 ??? TZ is 12 +/- in diff and not days!

Comment: Do you have a trigger ?